# How do input field methods (text_area, text_field, etc.) get attribute values from a record within a form_for block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes, overloading, getter

I have a standard Rails 2.3.5 app with a model called Post. Post has an attribute called url, and the following getter is defined:

```
def url
  p = 'http://'
  u = self[:url]
  u.starts_with?(p) ? u : "#{p}#{u}"
end
```

If I load up `script/console`, I can do `Post.first.url` and get the desired result (e.g. it returns http://foo.com if the attribute's true value is foo.com)

However, if I have a `form_for` block, and do something like `form.text_field :url`, it will *not* return the url with http:// prefixed; rather, it simply returns foo.com

How does form_for access attributes on ActiveRecord models? It seems to bypass any overloaded getters.

Answer (score 1):

```
def url_before_type_cast    
 p = 'http://'
 u = self[:url].capitalize
 u.starts_with?(p) ? u : "#{p}#{u}"    
end
```

Comment: Thanks; Will this work in both contexts (form.text_field *and* doing @post.url)?

Answer (score -1):

By returns to you mean sets?

The text field posts the data to your controller. (The create or update depending on)

In the controller:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
or
@post.update_attributes(params[:post])
```

is where the field is set.

If you want to implement the setter to add the http:// you should write your function as `def url=`.

Comment: Hi. I'm referring to the text field's value being populated by form.text_field :url