# `form_for` is bypassing model accessors. How to make it stop? (Or: How to make a custom attribute serializer?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I set these methods to automatically encrypt values.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def name=(val)
    super val.encrypt
  end
  def name
    (super() || '').decrypt
  end
```

When I try to submit the form and there is an error (missing phone), then the `name` attribute shows up garbled.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="Mg8IS1LB2A1efAeZJxIDJMSroKcq6WueyY4ZiUX+hfI=" name="user[name]" id="user_name">
```

It works when the validations succeeds. It also works in the console when I go line-by-line through my controller `#update`.

```
irb(main):015:0> u = User.find 1
irb(main):016:0> u.name
=> "Sue D. Nym"
irb(main):017:0> u.phone
=> "212-555-1234"
irb(main):018:0> u.update name: 'Sue D. Nym', phone: ''
   (10.0ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
irb(main):020:0> u.save
=> false
irb(main):029:0> u.errors.full_messages.join ','
=> "Phone can't be blank"
irb(main):031:0> u.build_image unless u.image
=> nil
irb(main):033:0> u.name
=> "Sue D. Nym"
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
  def update
    @user = User.find current_user.id
    @user.update user_params
    if @user.save
      flash.notice = "Profile Saved"
      redirect_to :dashboard
    else
      flash.now.alert = @user.errors.full_messages.join ', '
      @user.build_image unless @user.image
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

The view is somehow getting the encrypted value without going through `#name`, and only after a validation failure.

---

I reduced the controller to the absolute minimum and it fails immediately after `#update`. However, it's working on the console!

```
  def update
    @user = User.find current_user.id
    @user.update user_params
    render :edit
    return
```

---

I reduced my view to the absolute minimum and it shows the name, but only outside of `form_for`. I don't know why yet.

`edit.haml`

```
=@user.name
=form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  =f.text_field :name
```

`HTML source`

```
<span>Sue D. Nym</span>
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/users/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="C/ScTxfENNxCKgzG0qAlPElOKI7nOYxZimQ7BsB64wIWQ9El4+vOAfxX3qHL08rbr0sxRiJnzQti13e4DAgkfQ==">  
  <input type="text" value="sER9cjwa6Ov5weXjEQN2KJYoTOXtVBytpX/cI/aPrFs=" name="user[name]" id="user_name">
</form>
```

---

I noticed `attributes` still returned encrypted values so I tried adding this but `form_for` *still* manages to obtain the encrypted value and put it in the form!

```
  def attributes
    attr_hash = super()
    attr_hash["name"] = name
    attr_hash
  end
```

Rails 5.0.2

Comment: What version of Rails is this?

Comment: According to the post its Rails 5.0.2

Comment: Take a look at [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted). Although it basically does the same thing, it more "battle-tested". No need to roll your own solution here.

Comment: That requires a separate IV field for each table field, requires renaming each field to `encrypted_field`, and it is just like the answer below, except it switches to use `encrypted_name` as the real field and a virtual `name` method instead of `decrypted_name`.

Comment: @Robin that was added after my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can work around this by overloading `name_before_type_case`, I think this is actually the wrong place to be doing this kind of transformation.

Based on your example, the requirements here appear to be:

1. plaintext while in memory
2. encrypted at rest

So if we move the encrytion/decryption transformation to the Ruby-DB boundary, this logic becomes much cleaner & reusable.

Rails 5 introduced a helpful [Attributes API](https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/12/04/introduction-to-activerecord-and-activemodel-attributes-api/) for dealing with this exact scenario. Since you have provided no details about how your encryption routine is implemented, I'm going to use `Base64` in my example code to demonstrate a text transformation.

`app/types/encrypted_type.rb`

```
class EncryptedType < ActiveRecord::Type::Text
  # this is called when saving to the DB
  def serialize(value)
    Base64.encode64(value) unless value.nil?
  end

  # called when loading from DB
  def deserialize(value)
    Base64.decode64(value) unless value.nil?
  end

  # add this if the field is not idempotent
  def changed_in_place?(raw_old_value, new_value)
    deserialize(raw_old_value) != new_value
  end
end
```

`config/initalizers/types.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Type.register(:encrypted, EncryptedType)
```

Now, you can specify this attribute as encrypted in the model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name, :encrypted

  # If you have a lot of fields, you can use metaprogramming:
  %i[name phone address1 address2 ssn].each do |field_name|
    attribute field_name, :encrypted
  end
end
```

The `name` attribute will be transparently encrypted & decrypted during roundtrips to the DB. This also means that you can apply the same transform to as many attributes as you like without rewriting the same code.

Comment: Ooh that looks really nice! I'll try it! Yes, they are Base64 encoded.

Comment: Is there a way to list multiple attributes at once, like `attribute :name, :phone, :address1, :encrypted`? 

What does `cast value` do?

Comment: This updates the database every time you call `User.save` because it generates a new value with a new IV, whereas the getter/setter/getter_before_type_cast doesn't. `> u.save
   (3.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (2.0ms)  ...
  SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = $1, ...` `#serialize` consists of only `value.encrypt unless value.nil?`.

Comment: `> u=User.first
  User Load (15.8ms) ... > u.changed?
=> true` Yet nothing changed.

Comment: @Chloe `cast` is part of the `Type` interface, its purpose is taking a raw value from the user or DB and coercing it to the correct model value.

Comment: @Chloe you left out any details about the implementation of your encryption, so I wasn't able to address that at all. If you want to open a new Question, I will take a look. Generally speaking, how you generate the IV is a tradeoff. If you want greater security, you should randomly generate it for each value. That means you will be changing the data when it's not strictly necessary; using a static IV is less secure though.

Comment: Yes it generates a random IV for each value. But for some reason, this implementation calls `serialize` to generate a new encrypted value immediately after it loads (or calling `changed?`). So just loading the model will require a save of dozens of fields with new values, even if nothing changed. That could slow down the DB.

Comment: @Chloe try overloading [`changed_in_place?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3464cd5c288323ca115a4929d1e6b435c4afc8d4/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/value.rb#L83) to account for your encryption

Comment: @Chloe you don't want to be using class variables in that way, as they have some nasty side-effects when combined with inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you exposing it as name at all ?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    def decrypted_name=(val)
       name = val.encrypt
    end

    def decrypted_name
       name.decrypt
    end
end
```

Then you use `@model.decrypted_name` instead of `@model.name` as name is encrypted, and such saved in DB.

```
edit.haml
=@user.decrypted_name
=form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  =f.text_field :decrypted_name
```

And `name` if it is encrypted should not be handled directly but with this `decrypted_name` accessor.

Comment: How is this fundamentally different from what he has already? Why not use `name`, transparently from view's perspective?

Comment: Then I'll have to change all the attributes to `decrypted_[attribute]` everywhere in the code, and there are 1-2 dozen attributes I would like to encrypt, and I would like it to work transparently.

Answer (score 1):

I found this similar question: [How do input field methods (text_area, text_field, etc.) get attribute values from a record within a form_for block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303003/how-do-input-field-methods-text-area-text-field-etc-get-attribute-values-fr)

I added

```
  def name_before_type_cast
    (super() || '').decrypt
  end
```

And now it works!

Here is the full solution:

```
  @@encrypted_fields = [:name, :phone, :address1, :address2, :ssn, ...]
  @@encrypted_fields.each do |m|
    setter = (m.to_s+'=').to_sym
    getter = m
    getter_btc = (m.to_s+'_before_type_cast').to_sym
    define_method(setter) do |v|
      super v.encrypt
    end
    define_method(getter) do
      (super() || '').decrypt
    end
    define_method(getter_btc) do
      (super() || '').decrypt
    end
  end
```

Some docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html