# How can I encrypt a date value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have `char` and `text` values encrypted in the Postgres database, but how do I encrypt a date value like DOB? Do I put it into a `char` format and use `strftime` to convert it back & forth, or is there a standard Rails way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
add_column :users, :profile, :text      # migration

attribute :profile, :encrypted
store :profile, accessors: [:dob], coder: JSON
```

using the `EncryptedType` that I had already set up from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44578417/148844

> irb(main):028:0> u=User.first
>   
>     irb(main):029:0> u.dob=Date.new(1970,1,1)
>   
>     => Thu, 01 Jan 1970
>   
>     irb(main):031:0> u.profile
>   
>     => {"dob"=>Thu, 01 Jan 1970}
>   
>     irb(main):032:0> u.save
>   
>       SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "profile" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", 2017-07-11 01:48:01 UTC], ["profile", "Ast28WRZEEhfbHtI007dzYCASr2asS+PXRz/sjnXPquSkrANfSWxlCcW/LBUbLOB"], ["id", 1]]
>   
>        (24.2ms)  COMMIT
>   
>     => true

Docs: [#store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)