# How do I create a customer serializer for a hash attribute of a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  class JSONEncrypted
    def load(dbtext)
      JSON.load dbtext.decrypt
    end
    def dump(hash)
      (JSON.dump hash).encrypt
    end
  end
  store :profile, accessors: [:dob], coder: JSONEncrypted
```

However, it gives this error:

```
irb(main):006:0> u=User.first
irb(main):009:0> u.dob=Date.new(1970,1,1)
irb(main):010:0> u.dob
=> Thu, 01 Jan 1970
irb(main):011:0> u.profile
=> {"dob"=>Thu, 01 Jan 1970}
irb(main):017:0> JSON.dump u.profile
=> "{\"dob\":\"1970-01-01\"}"
irb(main):018:0> (JSON.dump u.profile).encrypt
=> "ZKr3SnJDsmdPllUpkveU0Ds6s2QO1zH7sPmquWZDEL0PYbvaBO6k8Y26+F99oEZy"
irb(main):012:0> u.validate
=> true
irb(main):015:0> u.save
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a User::JSONEncrypted, but was a ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess. -- {"dob"=>Thu, 01 Jan 1970}
```

#store: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

Customer serialization: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize#1343-Custom-serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
attribute :profile, :encrypted
store :profile, accessors: [:dob], coder: JSON
```

using the EncryptedType that I had already set up from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44578417/148844

However, if you still want a custom data type serializer, I also found https://www.viget.com/articles/how-i-used-activerecord-serialize-with-a-custom-data-type. Basically you have to return an instance of the exact same class as passed to `coder:`. I originally tried to subclass `JSON`, but discovered it was a module, so did not know how to subclass/submodule a module.